# Is there a place to add general information on a topic that might be useful, or should I ask/answer my own question?

Tags: discussion

There have been a couple of times where I've felt it could be useful to share information that doesn't necessarily fit into a QA format, and I'm wondering where I could put this on the site, *if it's relevant enough to put here at all.* For example:

1. In a recent [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/21874/7590) involving data sources, I copied a small list of links to government statistical agencies and central banks that often compile data; it's relevant to the question, but I've answered other questions that could benefit from similar information.
2. I've seen a few questions, similar to [this one](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21121/7590) asking about financial statements. I recently found that the Wikipedia page of [S&P500 components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) contains links, for every company, to their financial statements in EDGAR. I find this very useful.

Currently, these are my only specific examples, but is there a place where general, potentially useful information like this could go? The only options I can think of are a) the tag wiki, if a relevant tag exists, b) a self-answered question, although for point 1, I'm not sure what form that would take, if any, or c) the answer to any question where it's relevant.

I shy away from c) because at least with my answers, I tend to update them as time goes by with newer links, charts, etc. so I can see some of them falling out of sync. Alternatively, these two examples may not be great examples of general information that should be maintained anywhere and is best ignored for the time being.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  The [FAQ](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) even says so:

> It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

It's even encouraged.  If you have a good question and a good answer, throw it up.  If it's good, it'll get votes.  Just don't be surprised if someone else provides a good or even better answer than yours.

See Also: [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Comment: Right, I knew it's ok to ask/answer my own question, but I wasn't sure if it was appropriate in these cases because the questions I could think of were sort of vague. If I think of a question that would fit, I'll ask/answer it.

Answer (score 4):

Right now I don't think there is any place, however once the site graduates, there will be a blog for the site that members can contribute. I think these useful info could go in there. Right now you can create a psudo question say 'What are the site that give statistical info' and then put the links as answers

Comment: You could start the blog even before graduation, technically. [Christianity.se] has had a blog for quite a while.